# How can I display another filed title, not an event title on a jQuery FullCalendar?

Tags: events, fullcalendar

On the calendar I'd like to display another field title (like requestID#) along with a time reserved instead of the event title. I'm not sure where and how I need to make changes to the fullcalendar.js file. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventsource are you using?

If you are building your own, you could just put `requestID#` in the title property on the event object.

Or you could put it in a custom field like: `event.requestId` and change the title in the eventRender callback like so:

```
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-event-title').text(event.requesetId);
    }
```

Comment: I have removed the line "<span class='fc-event-title'>" + htmlEscape(event.title) + "</span>" + from the fullCalendar code, because I need to have just the time displayed in a day slot. What do you mean when you're suggesting to put requestID# in the title property on the event object? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Where do you get your data from? If you are building the JSON yourself, you can change the event object however you want. You should add the line you removed, and change the event.title value to the requestId.

Comment: I did it, I add the line back, so now the event title is back in the dayslot next to the event time. I also added the line of code "e.requestID = event.requestID" to the "Event Manipulation" part of the fullcalendar.js. Do I need to do that? Then changed the event.title value to the requestId. But it gives me an error "null" message. The data come from an asp.net mvc room reservation app where i'm trying to integrate the fullcalendar. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The exact error message is "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object" and it highlights this part of the fullcalendar.js code:
function htmlEscape(s) {
        return s
  .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
  .replace(/'/g, '&#039;')
  .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
    }

Comment: If you set event.title = requestId in the JSON you don't need to add any Event Manipulation.

Comment: In case if I'm not building the JSON, what are my options? Thanks!

Comment: Is the requestID in the JSON? If so you can use the method i described in my first answer now that you've added the `<span class="fc-event-title">`